# Page keeps loading forever

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Im using IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 so I add my Web Api but when I try to view the site it stays in a loading state like this:

[image]

Do not show any message or error just stays loading, I think that i miss some configuration or feature in my IIS but I don't know which one.

**Edit:** I use .Net framework, it is a REST .net web api like this [reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/01/05/introduction-to-rest-and-net-web-api/), the IIS have installed .Net versions 3.5 and 4.5, it's IIS not the express and the default IIS website runs fine.

**I would really appreciate any help.**

Comment: What kind of API? .Net framework ? .NetCore? Is the default IIs website running ? Is .net installed ? A screenshot of IE is not going to be enough for anyone to help you ... is this on IIS express or IIS ?

Comment: I add more info, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the timeout settings to a minimum level, say 10 seconds.
See if it throws a Timeout error.

Without much information from your side its hard to judge.

Perhaps it could be an external service you are trying to access(Web service) or a DB connection?

Comment: Using the event viewer gives me the warning 5139, the error 5002 and the info 5211 and apparently it's all about the WAS.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the application pool you assigned to your solutions runs under the correct version of .net framework and in integrated mode. I had similar issues when trying to run an mvc app in classic mode. Check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/) out.

**EDIT 1 - Reconfiguring IIS**
If problems persists then try the ASP.NET IIS Registration tool. Execute the followig command as administrator:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

At the end of [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) the different locations for aspnet_regiis are described. You should select a .NET Framework version corresponding to that of your project, run `aspnet_regiis` and assign the proper application pool to your app.

Comment: I tried with all the application pool and both modes, integrated and classic.

Comment: Please check **EDIT 1** of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here in 2023, try this in the windows cmd (`Run as administrator`):

```
> IISRESET
```

This will force restart all iis sites and this did the trick for me. If access is denied, just run the command again. You can also try

> IISRESET /noforce

to restart IIS gracefully.